# Points on a circle by angle not spaced evenly

Tags: c#, xna, geometry, angle

Given:

x = originX + radius * Cos(angle);

y = originY + radius * Sin(angle);

Why would the points not be evenly distributed around the edge of the circle?

Image of the result:

[image]

```
class Circle
{
    public Vector2 Origin { get; set; }
    public float Radius { get; set; }
    public List<Vector2> Points { get; set; }

    private Texture2D _texture;

    public Circle(float radius, Vector2 origin, ContentManager content)
    {
        Radius = radius;
        Origin = origin;
        _texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("pixel");
        Points = new List<Vector2>();

        //i = angle
        for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
        {
            float x = origin.X + radius * (float)Math.Cos(i);
            float y = origin.Y + radius * (float)Math.Sin(i);
            Points.Add(new Vector2(x, y));
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Points.Count; i++)
            spriteBatch.Draw(_texture, Points[i], new Rectangle(0, 0, _texture.Width, _texture.Height), Color.Red);
    }
}
```

Comment: See this question. The OP had the same issue you have. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598954/finding-points-on-perimeter-of-a-circle/14599469#14599469

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Math.Cos and Math.Sin take the angle in radians as opposed to degrees, your code should be:

```
float x = origin.X + radius * (float)Math.Cos(i*Math.PI/180.0);
float y = origin.Y + radius * (float)Math.Sin(i*Math.PI/180.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Points:

1) Math.Trig functions use Radians, not Degrees.

2) For this kind of precision, you would be better off using `double` instead of `float`.

3) The computer graphics/gaming pros avoid expensive functions like Sin and Cos, and instead use incremental <strike>integer</strike> pixel oriented approaches, [like Bresenham's Algorithms](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/bresenhams-line-and-circle-algorithms-r767), that give results as good or better than the straight-forward trigonometric math calculations and are *much* faster.

Comment: I haven't seen a preference for integer-based approaches for a *long* time ;) Modern (and not-so-modern) GPUs practically require you to use `float`.

Comment: @AndrewRussell  Right.  Obviously, I am not one of those Pros I mentioned. :-)  Is the rest of it still correct?

Comment: #1 is obviously correct. #2 is interesting - as you usually use `float` to reduce data size for better memory performance (and GPUs use it pretty much exclusively). You rarely need the precision of `double` (but then you must be able to know when you *do* need it). But C# only provides `double` versions of trig functions anyway. #3 I'm not sure is valid advice any more. It's rare that you want to draw an aliased circle outline (when you can do a nice anti-aliased thick-lined one on the GPU), and pixel poking operations are relatively very slow on modern GPUs!

Comment: @AndrewRussell Fair enough.

Comment: it is utterly inconceivable you would need to even think about optimization in this example use case.  use sin and cos.