# Evenly space multiple circles rotating around a point

Tags: c, math, animation, rotation, geometry

i've seen some questions about this but none of the solutions provided can work for me.
Basically, I'm making a program that can animate 2nd representations of atoms.

Say I need to rotate 8 small circles around a single point, how could I do this?

```
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
{
    x = 300 + sin(time + (45 * PI / 180.00)) * 95;
    y = 300 + cos(time + (45 * PI / 180.00)) * 95;
    fill_circle_on_screen(ColorBlue,x,y,5);
}
```

this doesn't work; I only see two circles rotating around the circle. There should be 8, as per the for loop, since I'm drawing 8 circles.
I tried to implement the answer here: [Finding Points On Perimeter Of a Circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598954/finding-points-on-perimeter-of-a-circle)

```
x = cx + r * cos(a * CV_PI / 180.0)
y = cy + r * sin(a * CV_PI / 180.0)
```

Where in my for loop: 300 is CX and CY. r is 95. a is 45. PI is CV_PI.

I don't exactly know why it's not working.
Does anyone know? Thanks.

Comment: You're drawing 8 small circles at the same location... note that you're not using `j` to determine the different position of each small circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
{
    x = 300 + sin(time + j*(2*PI / 8)) * 95;
    y = 300 + cos(time + j*(2*PI / 8)) * 95;
    fill_circle_on_screen(ColorBlue,x,y,5);
}
```